# Split multiple arrays into strings, skipping empty arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've made an AJAX call that has returned 20 arrays, some of which are empty, and others that have one or more items in them. I've split each array into strings using a for loop. The only problem is that this creates lots of empty strings from the arrays that were empty. Is there a way that I could skip the empty arrays in my for loop?

```js
success: function(data){
  console.log(data);
  for(x in data.data){
    var hashArray = data.data[x].tags;
    var hashStrings = hashArray.toString().split(',');
    var hashtags = '';

    for(var i = 0; i < hashStrings.length; i++) {
      hashtags = hashStrings[i];
      console.log(hashtags);  
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: could you please share `data` object which you are consoling in `success` handler?

Comment: What is result of `var hashStrings = hashArray.toString().split(',');`?

Comment: @guest271314: empty strings or strings with content.

Comment: @vilayP I've updated my question thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `.length` of the array. If it's `0` then it contains no elements, in which case `continue` to the next loop iteration. **EDIT** per comments for the array we're testing, seems more likely you'll be testing `data.data[x].tags.length`:

```
success: function(data){
  console.log(data);
  for(x in data.data){
    if (data.data[x].tags.length == 0) continue;

    var hashArray = data.data[x].tags;
    var hashStrings = hashArray.toString().split(',');
    var hashtags = '';

    for(var i = 0; i < hashStrings.length; i++) {
      hashtags = hashStrings[i];
      console.log(hashtags);        
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: @guest271314 I wasn't sure which array he meant.

Comment: I agree though on reviewing the code, you're probably right!

Comment: `if (data.data[x].tags.length !== 0)` , though issue could also be `var hashStrings = hashArray.toString().split(',');`

Comment: Yes that is it! if (data.data[x].tags.length == 0) continue; Thank you all :)